# Should I use convertView?

Tags: android, listview

Should I use convertView or create a new View in the following method?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
    return v;
}
```

or

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inflating every time the `View` is a bad decision from the performance perspective. The common pattern is to inflate your view only if the `convertView` is null. So, yes use the view the system is providing you. This way you can enable some magic optmization that allows to do not waste memory (view's recycle)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The null check is a must have?

Comment: I need to create textviews outside the check?

Comment: you should take a look to the ViewHolder pattern. You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)